# Add "Tax amount" to totals in "New order" email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, totals

I am trying to **improve the look of "New Order" email template**. I managed to get as far as adding the price of each item including and excluding tax.

Now, I want to add the **"Tax Amount"** to the totals section, how can I implement this? Please see the below image:

[image]

I know the totals are being rendered from `/http/app/design/frontend/themevendor/theme/template/sales/order/totals.phtml` in a foreach loop.:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
        <td colspan="6" <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
        <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

I am sure that I need to add the field in the `/http/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php` file but having some difficult time trying.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got somewhere. It might be not ideal but will do the trick for me. If anyone ever needs it.

Here is the updated `/http/app/design/frontend/themevendor/theme/template/sales/order/totals.phtml` file:

```
<?php
$totalTax = $this->getTotalTax();
?>
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
    <?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <tr class="<?php echo $_code?>">
        <td colspan="6" <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
        <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
            <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
            <strong><?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
            <?php else:?>
            <?php echo $this->formatValue($_total) ?>
            <?php endif?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php endif?>
      <?php if($_total->getLabel() == "Grand Total (Excl.Tax)"){ ?>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="6" <?php echo $this->getLabelProperties()?>>
                  <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
                  <strong><?php echo $totalTax["code"];?></strong>
                  <?php else:?>
                  <?php echo $totalTax["code"];?>
                  <?php endif?>
              </td>
              <td <?php echo $this->getValueProperties()?>>
                  <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
                  <strong><?php echo $totalTax["value"]; ?></strong>
                  <?php else:?>
                  <?php echo $totalTax["value"]; ?>
                  <?php endif?>
              </td>
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach?>
```

You also need to add this new function to the `/http/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php`. It's never a good practise to overwrite the core files, so just copy this file to this `/http/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/Totals.php` path and add this function below the `getTotals` function:

```
public function getTotalTax(){
      $totals = $this->_totals;
      $grandtotal_include;
      $grandtotal_exclude;
     foreach($totals as $total){
       $totalData;
       $totalData = $total->getData();
       if($totalData["code"] == "grand_total_incl"){
         $grandtotal_include = $totalData["value"];
       }
       if($totalData["code"] == "grand_total"){
         $grandtotal_exclude = $totalData["value"];
       }
     }
     $tax = $grandtotal_include - $grandtotal_exclude;
     round($tax, 2);
     $formattedTax = Mage::helper('core')->currency($tax, true, false);
     $returnTax = array("code" => "Tax Amount", "value" => $formattedTax);
     return $returnTax;
    }
```

I hope someone will find this useful.